# Log4j2 is not formatting output like specified / appender is not added I think

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm learning to use log4j2 for my application. To being with, I've added a single appender and Pattern layout with format specifier. However, the output is not following the specification. Even the INFO level statements are not being printed. 
Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder=ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE");
        appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "[%c{1}] %m\\n"));
        builder.add(appenderBuilder);

        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is a first Info log");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "This is a second Info log");
        logger.log(Level.ERROR, "This is a first Error log");
        logger.log(Level.FATAL, "This is a first fatal log");

    }
```

- Problems I'm facing are:

  1. The logging output is not following the pattern I've specified. I've
     tried changing the pattern and it still prints in the same format.
  2. I've added four logging statements, out of which only two are printed(ERROR and FATAL).

Outputs:

```
  Logging output for pattern ("%m\\n"): 
       14:42:06.046 [main] ERROR loghelper.log4j.Log2Helper - This is a first Error log
    14:42:06.049 [main] FATAL loghelper.log4j.Log2Helper - This is a first fatal log

Logging output for pattern ("%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"): 
        14:41:23.555 [main] ERROR loghelper.log4j.Log2Helper - This is a first Error log
    14:41:23.557 [main] FATAL loghelper.log4j.Log2Helper - This is a first fatal log
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The logging output is not following the pattern I've specified. I've even tried changing the pattern and it still prints the same. Also, I've added four logging statements, out of which only two are printed(ERROR and FATAL).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the Root Logger isn't configured (default to ERROR Level)
therefore error and above level logs are printed.

Secondly the builder isn't built after adding the appender.

```
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
```

SHOULD BE UPDATED TO

```
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);
    builder.build();
```

Comment: I added the the build statement. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Mohit almost had it. Even with builder.build() all you have accomplished is the creation of a Configuration. You haven't actually told Log4j to use it. For that you need to use

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
loggerContext.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

After all this I have to ask, why bother with programmatic configuration when you can just provide a file?

Comment: What should be the configuration object in my case? 

loggerContext.setConfiguration(configuration);

I haven't set configuration/ is not needed in my case.

Comment: If you don't need a configuration (i.e. - you are configuring with a file or using the default configuration) then none of this is necessary. Just put the log4j2.xml, log4j2.properties, or log4j2.yaml on the classpath or set the log4j2.configurationFile property to the location of the file.

Comment: I have a reason for doing this programmatic configuration. Its project specific.

Comment: Then I don’t understand your question about what the configuration should be. That is what you are creating with the builder. You just didn’t cake the build method to build it and then pass it to Log4J to use.